# MongoDB with LDAP authentication windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, ldap

Is it possible to LDAP authenticate MongoDB via mongo shell. I've installed Mongodb community edition on windows server 2012 R2. If possible please help me to configure LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is only available with Mongo Enterprise

[Mongo Enterprise authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms-enterprise/)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...